# Using Jinja/SQL for Dropdown Menu on Registration Form

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, dropdown

I am trying to create a registration form for college students where users will select the house/dorm in which they reside from a dropdown menu.

Instead of hardcoding each dorm name into HTML, I was hoping to use Jinja and a SQL table to display the options within the dropdown menu.

Here is what my HTML and Python code is looking like -- nothing appears in the menu when I run flask. How can I fix this?

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8EVt.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyabx.png)

Comment: You really should paste your code in the question. Adding it as an image makes it harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('inputUsername')
        password = request.form.get('inputPassword')
        password = request.form.get('inputConfirmPassword')
        do_something_else()
    houses = db.execute("SELECT name FROM houses")
    return render_template('register.html', houses=houses)
```